# How do I detect if a System.Windows.Forms.Label with AutoEllipsis is actually displaying ellipsis?

Tags: c#, winforms, label, ellipsis

I have a Windows Forms Application where I display some client data in a Label.
I have set label.AutoEllipsis = true.
If the text is longer than the label, it looks like this:

```
Some Text
Some longe... // label.Text is actually "Some longer Text"
              // Full text is displayed in a tooltip
```

which is what I want.

But now I want to know if the label makes use of the AutoEllipsis feature at runtime.
How do I achive that?

Solution

Thanks to max. Now I was able to create a control that try to fit the whole text in one line. If someone is interested, here's the code:

```vb
Public Class AutosizeLabel
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Label

    Public Overrides Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return MyBase.Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            MyBase.Text = value

            ResetFontToDefault()
            CheckFontsizeToBig()
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overrides Property Font() As System.Drawing.Font
        Get
            Return MyBase.Font
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As System.Drawing.Font)
            MyBase.Font = value

            currentFont = value

            CheckFontsizeToBig()
        End Set
    End Property


    Private currentFont As Font = Me.Font
    Private Sub CheckFontsizeToBig()

        If Me.PreferredWidth > Me.Width AndAlso Me.Font.SizeInPoints > 0.25! Then
            MyBase.Font = New Font(currentFont.FontFamily, Me.Font.SizeInPoints - 0.25!, currentFont.Style, currentFont.Unit)
            CheckFontsizeToBig()
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub ResetFontToDefault()
        MyBase.Font = currentFont
    End Sub

End Class
```

Could need some fine tuning (make the step size and the minimum value configurable with designer visible Properties) but it works pretty well for the moment.

Comment: why don't you check this property at run-time?

Comment: @Arseny: The the property is true the Label "can" use ellipsis if the text is to big. For a small text nothing is changed but the property is still true.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
private static bool IsShowingEllipsis(Label label)
{
    return label.PreferredWidth > label.Width;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated the Question with a control that autofits the text to fit in the label. @Phil: good point, too!

Comment: This does not work for labels that are multiple line like Vasily Ivanov's solution does.

Answer (score 7):

In fact, your Lable could be multiline. In this case, label.PreferredWidth wouldn't help. But you can use:

```
    internal static bool IsElipsisShown(this Label @this)
    {
        Size sz = TextRenderer.MeasureText(@this.Text, @this.Font, @this.Size, TextFormatFlags.WordBreak);
        return (sz.Width > @this.Size.Width || sz.Height > @this.Size.Height);
    }
```

Comment: I agree, your code works perfect. Max code did not work.

Comment: This is the superior solution